# Remove only specific duplicates in array using Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

Is there a way to remove specific duplicates in an array using Ruby? Example array:

```
["hello", "removeme", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]
```

I only want to remove duplicates of `"removeme"` on that array. The desired output is:

```
["hello", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]
```

Is there a method like this to get the desired output? `["hello", "removeme", "removeme", "hello", "testing"].uniq('removeme')`

Comment: What is the desired result if the array were `["hello", "removeme", "hello", "testing", "removeme"]`? I want to know if the choice of element to retain (here the first or second instance of `"removeme"`) is important.

Comment: Hi @CarySwoveland, desired result will be `["hello", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]` , I want to remove duplicate with specific string for example above i want to retain one `removeme` value in the array. I can't use `uniq` because it will affect `hello` value in array

Comment: You said, "i want to retain one `removeme` value in the array.", but I asked which one is to be retained. Saying, "desired result will be `["hello", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]`" suggests you wish to retain the first instance, but it could be that you don't care which one is retained. You need to clarify that. When clarifying questions it is always best to edit your question rather than elaborate in comments, as questions should be stand-alone--readers should not be required to read all the comments to understand the question.

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby problem so you should not have Rails tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block which removes duplicates based on the block's return value:

```
ary = ["hello", "removeme", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]

ary.uniq { |obj| obj.eql?('removeme') || Object.new }
#=> ["hello", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]
```

For elements equal to `'removeme'` we return `true` and for everything else (`'hello'`, `'hello'`, and `'testing'`), we return a new object: (note the different object ids)

```
"hello"    → #<Object:0x00007f9ab08590d8>
"removeme" → true
"removeme" → true
"hello"    → #<Object:0x00007f9ab0858d68> 
"testing"  → #<Object:0x00007f9ab08589f8>
```

All elements with the same return value are considered duplicates, i.e. `uniq` will treat `'removeme'` as a duplicate and anything else as unique regardless of its actual value. This allows the two identical `'hello'` strings to remain.

Instead of `Object.new`, you could also use the element's index:

```
ary.enum_for(:uniq).with_index { |obj, i| obj.eql?('removeme') || i }
#=> ["hello", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]
```

[`enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Object.html#method-i-enum_for) is needed, because `uniq` without a block returns a new array instead of an enumerator (which in turn is needed for chaining [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index)).

Comment: Clever! I tried to do something similar but tripped on the final step. I guess another way would be `n = 0; ary.uniq { |obj| obj.eql?('removeme') || n += 1 }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've added your approach with the element's index.

Answer (score 4):

What about rejecting all but the first occurrence of the word, like this.

```
def uniq_word(array, word)
  return array unless first = array.index(word)
  array.reject.with_index { |elem, index| index > first && elem == word }
end

array = ["hello", "removeme", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]

uniq_word(array, 'removeme')
#=> ["hello", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]
```

See [`Array#index`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:index), [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerator#with_index), and [`Array#reject`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:reject).

Or you could iterate the aray and copy only the first occurance into a new array:

```
def uniq_word(array, word)
  found = false

  [].tap do |result|
    array.each do |elem|
      if elem == word && !found
        found = true
        next
      end

      result << elem
    end
  end
end

array = ["hello", "removeme", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]

uniq_word(array, 'removeme')
#=> ["hello", "removeme", "hello", "testing"]
```

See:

Answer (score 3):

The following method could be used.

```
def removem(arr, to_remove)
  i = arr.index(to_remove)
  i.nil? ? arr : (arr - [to_remove]).insert(i, to_remove)
end
```

---

Suppose the given array is as follows.

```
arr = ["hello", "removeme", "hello", "goodbye", "removeme", "testing"]
```

Then,

```
removem(arr, "removeme")
  #=> ["hello", "hello", "goodbye", "testing", "removeme"]
removem(arr, "goodbye")
  #=> ["hello", "removeme", "hello", "goodbye", "removeme", "testing"]
removem(arr, "missing")
  #=> ["hello", "removeme", "hello", "goodbye", "removeme", "testing"]
```

In each example `arr` is unchanged.

See [Array#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-index) and [Array#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-insert)

Answer (score -2):

What about extending Array class by adding new method.

```
class Array
  def uniq_specific!(targets)
    found = {}
    targets.each { |target| found[target] = false }

    delete_if do |item|
      if targets.include?(item)
        if found[item]
          true
        else
          found[item] = true
          false
        end
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
end

array = ["hello", "removeme", "removeme", "hello", "world", "world", "testing"]
array.uniq_specific!(["removeme", "hello"])

array # => ["removeme", "hello", "world", "world", "testing"]
```

We define a new method uniq_specific! for the Array class that accepts an array of target elements as a parameter. It iterates over the array and removes all occurrences of each target element, except for the first one. Then, we call this method on the example array with the target values ["removeme", "hello"], which produces the desired output.

Comment: I'm downvoting because the first instances of both `"hello"` and `"removeme"` are removed, not just the latter, but even if the method were correct there is no reason to contaminate the `Array` class by adding a new method.

Comment: As you know, there were no such conditions in this issue, I proposed another implementation option.